# While-loop with XML package in R for variable length query

Tags: r, xml, while-loop

I have the following problem, I am scraping some data from the *Basketballreference* website, in it I will make several queries in the [player season finder](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi) part of the website, each query gives back multiple pages. I have been able to scrape it using the XML package of R:

```
library(XML)

URL="http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&type=per_poss&per_minute_base=36&per_poss_base=100&lg_id=NBA&is_playoffs=N&year_min=1980&year_max=&franch_id=&season_start=1&season_end=-1&age_min=0&age_max=99&shoot_hand=&height_min=0&height_max=99&birth_country_is=Y&birth_country=&birth_state=&college_id=&draft_year=&is_active=&debut_yr_aba_start=&debut_yr_aba_end=&debut_yr_nba_start=&debut_yr_nba_end=&is_hof=&is_as=&as_comp=gt&as_val=&award=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&qual=&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&c5stat=&c5comp=&c6mult=1.0&c6stat=&order_by=ws&order_by_asc=&offset="

numerals <- seq(from = 0, to = 7200, by = 100)
NBAlist <- list()
for(i in 1:73)
{
  URL1 <- paste(URL, numerals[i], sep = "")
  tablefromURL <- readHTMLTable(URL1)
  NBAlist[[i]] = tablefromURL[[1]]
}

NS = do.call(rbind, NBAlist)
```

To get the number 73 I will go and find the last page that still has players manually, which for one query is not much, but I intend to do many queries.

I thought that I could do a While loop and stop when it retrieves an empty table doing something like this:

```
while (NBAlist[[i]] !is.na()){...}
```

However when I did this as a test with offset 100000:

```
URL <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&type=per_poss&per_minute_base=36&per_poss_base=100&lg_id=NBA&is_playoffs=N&year_min=1980&year_max=&franch_id=&season_start=1&season_end=-1&age_min=0&age_max=99&shoot_hand=&height_min=0&height_max=99&birth_country_is=Y&birth_country=&birth_state=&college_id=&draft_year=&is_active=&debut_yr_aba_start=&debut_yr_aba_end=&debut_yr_nba_start=&debut_yr_nba_end=&is_hof=&is_as=&as_comp=gt&as_val=&award=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&qual=&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&c5stat=&c5comp=&c6mult=1.0&c6stat=&order_by=ws&order_by_asc=&offset=100000"

tablefromURL <- readHTMLTable(URL)
```

I do get a *Named list()*, and if I go further down the loop and do:

```
NBAlist[[1]] <- tablefromURL[[1]]
```

I get the following error: `Error in tablefromURL[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`.

I don't know how to proceed further, any help would be greatly appreciated